# Elvis operator doesn't work in Kotlin while the synthax seems correct

Tags: kotlin, compiler-errors, elvis-operator

I am learning Kotlin from [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5flXf8nuq60&t=302s) and at **35:45** he is running this code:

[image: attachment_2]

I've tried to run exactly the same code:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val x = readLine()?:"1"
    val y = readLine()?:"1"
    val z = x.toInt() + y.toInt()
    print(z)
}
```

But I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:662)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
at MainKt.main(Main.kt:4)
at MainKt.main(Main.kt)
```

[image: attachment_3]

Can somebody help me please? I am really a noob in Kotlin (and software programming too) and I haven't found an answer on the web.

Thank you.

Comment: `readLine` only returns null if it reads from a file and end of file has been reached. You are getting the empty string when you just press enter in the console.

Comment: Use _readlnOrNull()_ if you want to get _null_ instead of an empty string.

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code or errors, copy-paste the text instead: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1540818

Comment: @marstran First thank for your answer. Can you be more precise please. Yes i am getting getting the empty string when i press enter in the console and so where is the problem? It like that that i made the input as null no?

Comment: @lukas.j I am following a course on internet (see video link) so i prefer to learn what i made wrong.

Comment: @lukas.j `readlnOrNull` behaves exactly the same way as `readLine` on the JVM. It too will return the empty string.

Comment: @constellation_du_fion: What you are looking for is: _readln().ifEmpty { "1" }_

Comment: @marstran: was not aware that. Thank you for correcting me on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Elvis operator evaluates to the right operand only when the left operand is `null`. The empty string `""` is not the same as `null`.

`readLine()` returns null when it detects the "end of file". When reading from a file, this is obviously when reaching the end. When reading from stdin (the console's standard input), this is usually when you press Ctrl+D.

If you just press Enter, you are effectively inputting an *empty* line (`""`), not the "end of file".

If you want to get this kind of default value when you press Enter on the command line, then you should react to the empty string instead of null. As @lukas.j mentioned, one way to do this is to use [ifEmpty](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/if-empty.html) to provide a default:

```kotlin
val x = readln().ifEmpty { "1" }
```